# Self-hosted система управления проектами

Tags: agile, scrum, организация, project-management

Подскажите, пожалуйста, систему управления проектами, основанную на agile методологии (scrum, kanban), которую можно развернуть на своем хостинге.

Требования:

1. Открытая и бесплатная
2. Возможность развернуть на своем хостинге
3. Использует scrum-методологию
4. Похожа на Trello, но более гибкая в настройках и наглядная, например, позволит следить за общим ходом проекта (а не все спрятано в каточках как в Trello), статусом задач, эффективностью использования времени (графики, диаграммы - вот это все) и т.д. Jira отличный вариант, но она платная.

Приоритетны пункты 1,4. Если не self-hosted, то пускай онлайн, главное гибкость и требования, озвученные в пунтке 4

Понимаю, что требований слишком много, но вдруг кто-то слышал или использовал подобный продукт.

Хочу уйти от гугл доков и календаря, на что-то более эффективное.

Comment: я делал для себя обзор селфхостед решений год назад где-то
с ограничениями (до 10 пользователей, кажется, проверьте) - youtrack. оч неплохой показался. (если б не ограничения)
с плагинами - gitlab. (не очень люблю руби), 
возможно (но маловероятно, хотя черт его знает) - gogs
В остальном все очень плохо с селф-хостедом.

Comment: спасибо, количество пользователей не важно, больше для себя на личных проектах. а не селф-хостед решения есть интересные? а то Трелло даже с плагинами удручает

Comment: не селфхостеды не проверял. :) попробуйте youtrack тогда

Comment: @strangeqargo Оформите, как ответ хоть тогда, я вам плюс в карму поставлю

Comment: ща, я забыл про еще очень хорошее решение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я делал для себя обзор селфхостед решений год назад где-то:

Лидеров для меня было два:

1) phabricator - оч продвинутый, на него и [blender](https://www.blender.org/) и [wikimedia](https://www.wikimedia.org/) перешли, но надо разбираться в установке, ему желателен отдельный, выделенный инстанс mysql, либо чтобы ваши базы не пересекались с его по именам. В остальном он ок.

2) youtrack - c ограничениями (до 10 пользователей, кажется, проверьте) - неплохой показался (если б не ограничения).

С плагинами - gitlab (не очень люблю руби), 
Возможно (но маловероятно, хотя черт его знает) - gogs

В остальном все очень плохо с селф-хостедом (редмайны, мантисы, траки дико страшные), с другой стороны, возможно плагины для agile там тоже есть. Но они просто оч старые по архитектуре и страшные по внешнему виду.

Comment: отлично, спасибо! буду разбираться. может кто-нибудь дополнит список своими ответами

Comment: а зачем вам scrum, если вы для себя используете? канбаны-доски и т.д.

Comment: scrum же не запрещает использовать свои принципы в личных целях. да, митинги проводить не буду) просто нравится подход по организации проекта, который применяется в агиле-методиках. вот, решил перенять, потому что гугл-доки немного не то, отнимает много времени, нет наглядности

Comment: а есть какие-то советы по самоорганизации?

Comment: ну просто сам баг-трекер с приоритезацией задач вполне себе доску заменит для одного пользователя, имхо. А вообще тема  с багтрекерами полезная, пробовал для себя такое, надо вернуть )

Comment: @while1pass - хороший проект менеджер 
 https://waffle.io/

Answer (score 2):

Более-менее подходит GitLab CE.

> 1. Открытая и бесплатная

GitLab CE (Community Edition) открытый и бесплатный. (Есть ещё GitLab EE: открытый, но платный.)

> 2. Возможность развернуть на своем хостинге

Есть, но можно и облачным пользоваться.

> 3. Использует scrum-методологию

`<режим-зануды>`Scrum всё-таки используют люди, а ПО может его поддерживать или хотя бы не мешать. `</режим-зануды>` Давайте пройдёмся по практикам скрама и посмотрим, что из них поддерживается.

#### Задачи

- Есть возможность заводить задачи в трекере. Трекер привязан к репозиторию с проектом. Если вам нужен трекер сам по себе, можно создать пустой проект.
- У задачи есть уникальный номер, заголовок, описание, комментарии, связи с другими задачами и мерж-реквестами, автор и исполнитель.
- Сами задачи можно описывать как [пользовательские истории (user story)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.B8), можно добавлять в них DoD (Definition of Done, критерий готовности) и что угодно другое, но всё это будет в одном текстовом поле (т.е. нельзя иметь кастомные поля в задаче, как в JIRA).
- Важность и категорию задачи можно обозначить с помощью меток.
- Пока что у задач нет иерархии, [возможно что она появится](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/4058).
- Можно использовать шаблоны для задач и мерж-реквестов. Это неплохо помогает стандартизировать их вид и содержание.
- У задач нет привязки к дате, так что календарь заменить не получится.

В одном из последних релизов появилась возможность организовывать задачи в так называемые «доски задач» (issue boards). Они похожи на канбан, но более гибки. Досок может быть несколько, например, на одной вы разделяете задачи между бэклогом и спринтами, а на другой отслеживаете выполнение внутри спринта.

#### Планирование и обратная связь

Если вы захотите разграничивать задачи по спринтам, для этого можно будет использовать Milestone'ы. В самом GitLab они используются для разграничения релизов — [пример](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/milestones).

Оценка задач по времени вроде бы отсутствует. Есть фича для учёта потраченного времени — Time tracking — но она идёт отдельным продуктом.

> позволит следить за общим ходом проекта (а не все спрятано в каточках как в Trello), статусом задач, эффективностью использования времени (графики, диаграммы - вот это все)

Есть Cycle Analytics – аналитика циклов производства ПО. Показывает данные о том, с какой скоростью выполняются задачи и на какие этапы уходит сколько времени. Подробнее — [в документации](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/cycle_analytics.html).

#### Роли

В GitLab есть пользователи, есть уровни прав в проекте. Не вполне представляю, какая поддержка со стороны ПО *нужна* для выполнения этих ролей. Разве что можно ограничить права на создание задач, меток milestone'ов.

#### Собрания

Опять же, не представляю, как можно поддержать эту практику. Исключение — процесс планирования, но про него уже сказано выше.

> 4. Похожа на Trello, но более гибкая в настройках и наглядная.

Не работал с Trello, не могу сравнить.